# if the sign_in is not true but the password is, It prints welcome which it should not since I have the 'and' included in the code thank you

Tags: python, string, variables

```
with open('textfile1.txt', 'r') as f:
 if sign_in and password in f.read():
    print("welcome")
 else:
    print("not working")
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is parsed as if it were `if sign_in and (password in f.read()):` Does that explain the problem>?

Comment: appreciate it Barmar :)